# What is the practical use of philosophy?

Tags: metaphysics, applied-philosophy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is philosophy useful? Examining the practical, impactful, real-life benefits of getting a degree in philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/how-is-philosophy-useful-examining-the-practical-impactful-real-life-benefits)

What is the practical use of philosophy?

How could scientists and other laymen benefit from philosophy?